# How to protect user's "channel" on socket.io and node js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I created a social network, that is growing very well. And I'd like to implement live notifications using socket.io and node.

Well. Already did it, and it work this way...

USER A send message to USER B, than node server is notified via emit to write to the channel that bellongs to user B.

Each user connects to it's own channel when browsing the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect( 'https://notificationserver.com/' );
socket.on( 'notifications_USERID', function( data ) {
    var data_type=data.data_type;
    //sample
    if(data_type=="message"){
      $.notify("You got a new message", "success");
    }

});
</script>
```

Pretty simple. The user's channel is notifications_USERID.

That is not secure offcourse. If someone saves the html page to it's computer and load it, they will starget getting that particular user notifications.

So, what would be the best approaches to make it secure and accessible only be the real logged user?

**UPDATE**

I use curl to send data to the node server, like this:

```
 $curl = curl_init();                                        
 $data = json_encode(array("receiverid"=>$uid,"secret"=>"SOMESECRET"));                                                         
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://notificationserver:1334");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
 curl_exec($curl);
```

**THIS IS MY APP.JS FILE**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var key="SOMESECRET";

var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        var jsonString = '';

        request.on('data', function (data) {

            body += data;
            jsonString += data;
            if (body.length > 1e6) { 
                request.connection.destroy();
            }
        });
        request.on('end', function () {


             var json_data=JSON.parse(jsonString);
             var receiverid=json_data.receiverid;
             var secret=json_data.secret;


             if(secret==key){
                NewMessageNotify(receiverid); 
             }else{
                request.connection.destroy(); 
             }


        });
    }else{
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        response.end();
    }

}).listen(1334);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

function NewMessageNotify(receiverid){
    io.sockets.emit("notifications_"+receiverid,{ data_type: "message" }); 
}
```

Comment: How are you sending messages from the server?  Can we see that code?  I would think that you'd authenticate a connecting user, then keep track of which socket.id is connected to which authenticated person.  Then, when you want to send a message to that person, you send it only to the socket that was authenticated as them.  Your scheme of using a custom message name for each user technically allows anyone to listen to all messages.

Comment: If you want to get the most out of StackOverflow, please check back within 20-30 minutes of posting your question to see if people need some help understanding your question.  The vast majority of people who might be able to help will see your question in the first 30-60 minutes.  If it's not entirely clear and you aren't responding to questions being asked, people will just pass on by and you will miss out on their help.  This place does not work like a typical forum where you post and come back 24 hrs later.  If your question is not clear, it will be closed before that.

Comment: Hello. I,m writing to the node server using php. I also send some kind of password and the server will notify the user only if the "password" match. This way i avoid someone unwanted publishing to it.

Comment: I don't think we can help you without seeing the server-side code here so we can understand how you send messages.  It sounds like you've got a security model that doesn't work if you're relying on message names to distinguish messages per user.

Answer (score 4):

You have a broken security model and are sending all messages for all users to everyone (you are essentially broadcasting them).  With a slight tweak of the client-side javascript or a rogue piece of javascript run from any computer to hook in at a slightly lower level than `socket.io`, any user could listen to all the messages.

In this code:

```
function NewMessageNotify(receiverid){
    io.sockets.emit("notifications_"+receiverid,{ data_type: "message" }); 
}
```

The `io.sockets.emit()` part sends that message to all open sockets.  That is not what you want to do at all.  You want messages for "Bob" to only be sent to Bob's socket.  Then, nobody else ever has a chance to view them except whomever authenticated themselves to you as Bob.

So, to send Bob's messages only to Bob's socket, you have to maintain some correlation between Bob and his socket.  Typically, this would be done as part of the authentication process (which you don't show) so when someone makes a socket.io connection to your server and is successfully authenticated as Bob, you would record a link between Bob and a specific socket.  I don't know socket.io well enough to know if it has a built-in mechanism for maintaining that link, but I do know a couple ways you could do it.

1. If you aren't going to have zillions of users, you could use the chatroom capabilities.  When Bob logs in with a unique userID, you could join him to a chatroom with his name.  Then later when you want to send Bob a message, you just broadcast to the chatroom with his name.  He would be the only listener to that chatroom since your server would never put anyone else into it.  This is slightly a perversion of what chatrooms were designed for, but since your userIds have to be unique, it lets you use the username as a chatroom name and socket.io will keep the link between name and socket for you automatically.
2. You can create your own data structure of users and socket.id.  When a given user connections to your server and is successfully authenticated, you just add them to your data structure.  When they disconnect, you remove them.

Sample code:

```
var users = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // new socket connection here
    // authenticate the user
    // after successful login and authentication, add them to our data structure
    var username = "...";
    users[username] = socket;


    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        // remove them from our data structure
        delete users[username];
    });
});
```

Then, to send data to a particular user:

```
function NewMessageNotify(receiverid){
    // get socket for that specific user
    var socket = users[receiverid];
    if (socket) {
        socket.emit("notifications",{ data_type: "message" }); 
    }
}
```